# Proving $\lim _{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n} \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-n x^{2}} d x=0$

Tags: real-analysis

How to prove the following?
\begin{equation}
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{n} \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-n x^{2}} d x=0
\end{equation}

Comment: Do you know what the integral is when you change the lower limit to $0$?  Do a change of variable with $u=x\sqrt n$  Then you need to justify that as $n$ gets large most of the area is between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Hint : $ e^{nx^2}>nx^2$

Answer (score 2):

Some **hints**:

- For $x \geq 1$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ you have $e^{-nx^2} \leq e^{-nx}$
- $\int_1^{\infty}e^{-nx}dx = \frac{e^{-n}}{n}$

Now, you can bound $\sqrt{n} \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-n x^{2}} dx$ easily from above.

Answer (score 0):

$$I_n= \sqrt{n} \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-n x^{2}} dx$$ Let $x=\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}$ to make
$$I_n=\int_{\sqrt n}^{\infty}e^{-t^{2}} dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}  \left(1-\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{n}\right)\right)$$

Using the asymptotics of the error function
$$\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{n}\right)=1-\frac{e^{-n}}{\sqrt\pi }\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{ n} } -\frac{1}{2n\sqrt{ n} }+\cdots\right)$$
$$I_n\sim \frac {e^{-n}} {2\sqrt{ n} }$$ which is a very good approximation of $I_n$ even if $n$ is small (for $n=3$, the exact value is $0.00001958$ while the asymptotics gives $0.00002057$).